# Vector Subscript failing to add elements

Tags: c++, vector, cin, subscript

After writing some pretty terse C++ using the sub script operator, I have a small error in the program - there's no output.

I input this (Linux)

```
54 73 89 43 38 90
```

in then hit Cntrl + D for EOF. The program outputs nothing and stops executing.

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
vector<unsigned> scores(11, 0); //11 buckets, all initially 0
unsigned grade;
while(cin >> grade) //read the grades
{
   if(grade <=100) //handles only valid inputs
  {
   ++scores[grade/10]; //increment counter for the current cluster
  }
 }
}
```

I haven't changed my settings in VIM so the coding style is slightly off. I cannot conceive what is wrong, the while loop is pretty standard. It reads into grades until it find the stream is not valid. I then check the input for being less than 100 (inclusive). The final piece of code (it's pretty terse) find the correct element in the vector to increment the counter.

I have a feeling it could perhaps be my input that's causing the program to not output.

EDIT 1: I added the output statement, I did this by using dereferencing a  which is always a reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
vector<unsigned> scores(11, 0); //11 buckets, all initially 0
unsigned grade;
while(cin >> grade) //read the grades
{
   if(grade <=100) //handles only valid inputs
  {
   ++scores[grade/10]; //increment counter for the current cluster
  }
 }
for(auto it = scores.begin(); it != scores.end(); ++it) {
cout << *it << endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: By the way, `vector<unsigned> scores(11);` will leave you with eleven 0s as well.

Comment: Huh? I was just saving you from explicitly putting 0 in the argument list when you don't have to. No one mentioned an initializer list.

Comment: You could use "using namespace std;" instead of those four "using std::"-statements.

Comment: Why the downvote? A question with MWE and complementary test input. It doesn’t get much better than that. Yes, the error is trivial … but still!

Comment: @dutt You could, but then people here on Stack Overflow would (rightly) criticise you for it. You’re not supposed to do that usually.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Aha, thoughts along the lines of that you're exposing things you're not using?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you're right, I repent my downvote and will retract it. I've just been looking at too many cases recently of people making this mistake-- writing a lot of code before testing anything.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My thoughts exactly. I always write out each using deceleration after being informed one general statement is frowned upon.

Comment: @Beta Tunnel vision Beta. I was too focused on writing the subscript instead of concentrating on the whole program. Thank you for repenting your downvote though.

Comment: @chris I see. Default initiation. I tend to write in both the arguments for clarity and it's easy to mistake it for a list initialization when looking back at code.

Comment: @dutt Along the lines, yes. If you open the whole namespace you lose control over what an unqualified name refers to; granted, `cout` in’t going to cause problems. `min` or `find` might. Worse, if you open *several* namespaces you might get namespace clashes.

Comment: @TheBlueCat, Value-initialization, actually, since it's an `unsigned`.

Comment: Just noticed a typo in my comment to Chris.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see your point and will try to use "using namespace ..." less :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a feeling it could perhaps be my input that's causing the program to not output.

Not quite. It's the absence of output statements in your program that's causing it to not output.

Comment: Shit. After writing this elegant piece of code, I forget perhaps the easiest part; I even have the using declarations in the global scope too. Thank you for pointing this out. I should have double check my code before I posted. Nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: +1 I can't believe you're getting upvotes with an answer that essentially says "you forgot to write the program" :-)

Comment: @TheBlueCat, Well, I know I've made the same mistake of not outputting anything on many more than one occasion. It's really easy to forget to do so sometimes.

Comment: @chris I've learnt two lessons from this post: Always triple, double check your code before submitting it online to SO or Git. Secondly, I need to stop for a few minutes, slow down and think carefully what the program is doing. Mistakes happen.